# How to properly call multiple functions?

Tags: java

I have to write a program where there is these three methods/functions (I have trouble differing between the two lol, and I renamed them for this post):

```
public static double func(Scanner input)
public static double func(String parseString)
public static double funcInFile(String filename)
```

I understand that to call these, I need to create a main method at the bottom of my code (correct?) But I don't know how to go about it for this specific program.  I know that the format of it is: funcName(parameters);

But I'm a bit confused on what parameters I put in for each one.  For the first method it's supposed to return a running total of all inputs.  For the second one, I'm unsure of what to put since it's using (String parseString) but it's supposed to do the same computation as the first one. For the third function, it's supposed to read from a file and sum any real numbers in it as well.

I already wrote the code for each method but my last step is using the main method to call the functions.  Here's what I have:

```
public static double main (String[] args) {
  func(Scanner input); 
  func(String parseString);
  funcInFile(String filename);
```

It's giving me errors if I keep it like this, so I know I'll probably have to change the parameters.  Thank you!

Comment: its unclear what you are trying to get done. are you trying to take user input using scanner parse that string and then write to file?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, this is a Q&A site not a tutorial site. Your question indicates that you may need to review Java syntax a little more before you continue, I advise a little more self-study before asking here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not clear what you are trying to achieve but here is the code snippet drafted based on your question and my understanding on what you may be looking for.

import java.util.Scanner;
public class MultiFunCall {

```
public static void main(String... args){

    MultiFunCall obj =   new MultiFunCall();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    obj.func(input); 
    obj.func("Some String Value");
    obj.funcInFile("file.txt");


}


public void func(Scanner input){

}

public void func(String parseString){


}

public void funcInFile(String filename){

    
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I can help u little bit :-)
I am also new in Java/Kotlin but i think this should be correct.

From Google: A method, like a function, is a set of instructions that perform a task. The difference is that a method is associated with an object, while a function is not.

The Programm (Java) starts always with this method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
//here is your Code
}
```

i don't no how you wanna convert a  String funcInFile(String) and get a return value of double .. but i think you have your code....

**My Example:**

```
    public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double convertedString;
        String doubleString = "3.5";

    //Here i call my Methode(Function)
    // i give my function a String ("3.5") and get back a double (3.5d)
        convertedString = stringToDouble(doubleString);

        System.out.println("My Double is: " + convertedString);
        System.out.println("---------------- ");


// a String how is not possible to convert
    // i give my function a String ("a1.0") and get back the Error(Exception)
        doubleString = "a1.0";
        convertedString = stringToDouble(doubleString);
        System.out.println("My WrongDouble is: " + convertedString);

    }

    private static double stringToDouble(String number) {
        double doubleNumber;
        //Try Catch if something goes wrong
        try {
            //makes a Double to a string
            doubleNumber = Double.parseDouble(number);

        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("This String is not possible to Pars to a double");
            System.out.println(e);
            System.exit(0);
        }
        return doubleNumber;
    }

}
```

Output:

```
My Double is: 3.5
----------------
This String is not possible to Parse to a double
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "a1.0"

Process finished with exit code 0
```